# RESTful standard for nested JSON request

Tags: json, rest, standards, hierarchy, restful-architecture

I am writing a RESTful web service and have landed into a dilemma to which I am finding no clear answers. I  need to create a `bill` resource. I have two approaches and need suggestions over which one to use and why:

**Approach-1**

Build a big JSON payload and let the backend validate and create the nested resources. The JSON request looks like this:

```
 {
      'type_id' : ,
      'supply_state_id' : ,
      'consumer' : 
      {
           'name'  : ,
           'mobile_number' : ,
           'address' : 
           {
                'address1' : ,
                'city' : ,
                'zipcode' : ,
           },
      },
      'consignee' : 
      {
           'name' : ,
           'mobile_number' : ,
           'email' : ,
           'gstin' : ,
           'address' : 
           {
                'address1' : ,
                'city' : ,
                'zipcode' :
           }
      },
      'dated' : ,
 }
```

Note that the above structure has reached the second-level nesting, which as per my findings so far is not sugested. 
To eliminate the nesting I have an alternative, suggesting that all the nested resources to be first created and then their object `id`s to be used in the targetted resource i.e. `bill`.

**Approach-2**

Identify all the nested resources, create then in separate API hits, use their `id`s to create the final/targetted `bill` resource

First, we create two `address` resources using the json payload:

```
{
    'address' : 
    {
        'address1' : ,
         'city' : ,
         'zipcode' : ,
    }
}
```

say it returns the response from which we get the `address_id`and then we use that to create a `consumer` and a `consignee` resource:

*consumer*

```
{
    'consumer' : 
    {
         'account_id' : ,
         'name'  : ,
         'mobile_number' : ,
         'address_id' : ,
    }
}
```

*consignee*, using a separate `address_id`

```
{
    'consignee' : 
    {
        'name' : ,
        'mobile_number' : ,
        'email' : ,
        'gstin' : ,
        'address_id' : ,
    }
}
```

now we use the `consumer_id` and `consignee_id` from the above requests to create the desired resource

```
{
    'type_id' : ,
    'supply_state_id' : ,
    'consumer_id' : ,
    'consignee_id' : ,
    'dated' : ,
}
```

Both approaches have their own PROs and CONs over the other. I will highlight the major ones:

Approach-1:

- *PRO*: favors performance and readability
- *CON*: huge payload due to nesting of resources

Approach-2:

- *PRO*: modular and simplistic approach
- *CON*:  low performance due to multiple API calls

**Please suggest what approach should be used and why.**

If you could, please answer considering below:

- Performance
- Code maintainability (approach-1 has higher code complexity over the approach-2 from the back-end perspective and vice versa from the front-end perspective)
- Applications grow, hence the requests might get even bigger in JSON

Comment: Have you considered using GraphQL (https://www.howtographql.com/) for your API? It specializes in solving this very problem.

Comment: Thank you @fried-brice I will look into it. However my application is already in production phase and I cannot suggest such major makeover yet

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer approach two if your consumer or consignee or other nested object pops up in multiple bills, it might be slightly less readable, but you'll have some kind of consumerID anyway, so I'd say that loss is quite small.

About the multiple calls thing, you will only need to send the consumer-creation-json with the first bill, and I'm guessing you hope to use the same consumer a few times.